# Making a leaderboard using local storage and it's not saving

Tags: javascript, timer, local-storage

I'm working on a memory game web app and I'm trying to create a leaderboard using a table, here's what the code looks like:

```
function scoreLeaderboard() {
  let name = prompt('What is your name?');
  localStorage.setItem('name', name)
  localStorage.setItem('score', cardsWon.length);
  addToLeaderboard();
}

function addToLeaderboard() {
  leaderboard.innerHTML = `<li>${localStorage.getItem('name')} - ${localStorage.getItem('score')}`
  console.log(localStorage);
}
```

The problem now is that when I reload the page, the score disappears and the local storage gets wiped, how could I fix that? Also, I would like to make it display the results in order (from the most points to the least points) and I was also interested in making it so that you could get extra points for finishing it fast but I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example demonstrating the problem?  Currently this code doesn't do anything when the page is loaded.  It's entirely possible that you have other code which is removing or overwriting your values.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with `window.localStorage` or `window.sessionStorage`. The difference is that `sessionStorage` lasts for as long as the browser stays open, `localStorage` survives past browser restarts. The persistence applies to the entire web site not just a single page of it.

Have a look through these links: (If there is a problem with *this* peice of code, you'll find the answer in these links, but it could be a problem with another part affecting this.)

Browser Storage - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

localStorage - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage

Answer (score 0):

### About the persistence of the information...

On the `scoreLeaderboard` function you are overwriting any info that was previously registered, as the keys 'name' and 'score' are being set, so you could try some dynamic key naming, like `'name'+index`, where `index` is any value that is dynamically being changed as new games are being finished.

### About the order of the results...

You can, before displaying the info, put all the keys retrieved by the localStorage API in something like a array, sort it the way you like, or manually in a loop, or with a `loop()` alike method, and then relationating the scores with the names.

### About the finishing fast bonus...

You can get a variable with the time the player starts playing like

```
let startTime = Date.now();
```

and then make the same when the player finishes it

```
let startTime = Date.now();
```

you can then subtract it and check if it is inside any rule you want, like reward the player with X points if it finishes in 30 seconds

```
if((startTime-finishTime) < 30000){ 
//Gives him X points 
}
```

Comment: im using a name prompt to ask for the name, does that not work?

Comment: I think it is not the issue itself. But have in mind that when you do localStorage.setItem('name', name), you are putting info inside a "variable" named "name", so everytime this line is called, you are overwriting the value inside that same space on localStorage